# DKIM signing for subdomain issue

Tags: email, spf, dkim, opendkim

I am in an environment that sends emails from different sources. We're a Google Workspace environment as well.

The flow is as such:
A user (test@domain.tld) in Gmail sends an email to an email group (testgroup@listserv.domain.tld) that resides on our listserv (postfix)
This group (testgroup@listserv.domain.tld) is made up of Google users that reside in domain.tld
When the email is sent from the listserv.domain.tld it arrives in Gmail with a "DKIM FAIL domain domain.tld" in the "View original" headers (SPF is configured properly and so it doesn't get flagged spam/phishing)

test@domain.tld -> email -> testgroup@listserv.domain.tld (postfix server we control) -> sends test@domain.tld email to testgroup@listserv.domain.tld subscribers (Google accounts that reside in domain.tld) -> DKIM fails domain domain.tld

Looking at the email data, the d=domain.tld and NOT d=listserv.domain.tld

---

So after extensive testing, I believe I have stumbled on WHAT I need to do to get this working, however I am not familiar with how to do it.

What to do:
On the listserv.domain.tld server, use opendkim configure and generate the key/pair (done)
On our DNS host, create listserv._domainkey.listserv.domain.tld with the above generated public key (done)

The issue I can't figure out is this:
my assumption is that postfix/mailman/opendkim should take in the original email, and then sign it with it's own dkim private key then send it out to the members of testgroup@listserv.domain.tld and when it arrives the email DKIM domain header SHOULD say "DKIM PASS domain listserv.domain.tld"

However, it's still saying "DKIM FAIL domain domain.tld"

If I send an email from the CLI of the postfix server to either testgroup@listserv.domain.tld OR me@domain.tld the "DKIM PASS domain listserv.domain.tld" is present. So everything is configured correctly IF the email comes directly from @listserv.domain.tld and is not sent via/sent on behalf/sent from @domain.tld

Answer (score 3):

A message can have multiple DKIM signatures, and normally they are all evaluated during message processing. Adding a valid signature with `d=listserv.domain.tld` does not change the fact that the existing signature for `d=domain.tld` is invalid after your mailing list makes modifications.

Google's summary display chooses one DKIM result to display and has probably prioritized the exact domain match over the subdomain. If you look at the actual message headers you should be able to see the results for each individual signature in the `Authentication-Results` header, similar to the following:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@example.com header.s=bar header.b=VjtN0uuE;
       dkim=fail header.i=@subdomain.example.com header.s=foo header.b=e04DhOVX;
[...]
```

The only way to avoid an existing signature failing after message modification is to strip the signature off of the message. An invalid signature should not cause the message to be treated worse than a missing signature, so that may be an excessive amount of effort to fix a cosmetic issue with Google's method of summarizing authentication results.

Comment: Yeah from all my testing, it never included the d=listserv.domain.tld, google always seemed to have d=domain.tld

I just want everything green and signed haha but I do see that DKIM isn't necessarily a failure if SPF is configured properly, which is working.